# Excel "User Experience" Popup?

Tags: excel

When I open Excel, and load an Add-In, I get this dialog appearing (with the name removed for this question): "Adding __ library built on ____ at ____".

[image]

When I click on "Was this information helpful?", I get another popup: "Was this information helpful?" "Your response affects future updates of this information and is returned to Microsoft through the Microsoft Customer Experience Improvement Program."

[image]

This would just be a minor annoyance, except that it also happens with my code uses OLEAutomation to open Excel and set the Add-In to "Installed"!

This appears even though Excel is set to not Display Alerts!

Can this be turned off in Excel or in the system?

This is a major roadblock in the system I'm implementing.

**Edit**

By turning off the "*Send us information about your use and performance of Office software to help improve your Microsoft experience.*" setting in the Trust Center / Privacy Options, the "*Was this information helpful?*" link is gone from the popup. But the popup is still there.

Comment: I've set the computer's group policy to not be a part of the "Improvement Program" and done the same in the "Action Center".  It still pops up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the XLL is popping up the dialog.  But they'd never seen it with the extra "Was this information helpful?" link, so thought it wasn't theirs.